# Anylogic Network - Agent not following path

Tags: anylogic

I have a layout defined for agents to move from one rectangular node to another, based on a list in a database. So for example, agent 1 will go to 'lane' 701, then on to 702, etc.

The layout looks like this:

[example of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/766L3.png)

The agents move enter from the top left, along the x to the end of that row, then down to the bottom and out to the right, visiting the 'lanes' on their way.

However, I've noticed that one agent has its first lane in the bottom right so rather than following the path across and then down, it's using the shortest distance and moving on the diagonal straight to the lane in the corner:

[movement behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGckk.png)

Is there something in the software that I can set to strictly follow the paths set? I cannot work out why the agent is breaking the path so I can only assume it's something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first place, your agent is doing this diagonal probably because you have 2 different networks... if your destination is not in the current network, then the agent will use the shortest distance to the destination, which seems to be your case.

On the other hand, you can't control how the agents move on your network, and it will always take the shortest path or some optimized option... in order to make them follow the path you want, you need to generate intermediary destinations.

Comment: oh ok. I assumed that creating a network meant that the nodes and paths were used as nodes and edges, so the shortest path between nodes was calculated using a graph? it seems a bit odd that you would bother with paths at all if it's just going to use shortest path outside the network paths.

Comment: no no, it will take the shortest path using the network, but in your case, you probably have several networks and you haven't realized it.. or maybe your agent started outside the network... be careful with that

Comment: yes, i can see what you mean. it may be something about the agent starting outside the network as once it reaches its first goTo destination it then follows all the paths. It's just getting to that first node that seems to move outside the path system.

Comment: "it may be something about the agent starting outside the network". It will be *exactly* that. Unless an agent is given an initial location which is a node *on the same network as the next move-to destination*, it will 100% move in a straight line to that point. Any sets of nodes that are not connected by paths to the other nodes (i.e., 'islands' of nodes and paths) are by definition in another network. (Check the expansion of the relevant agent type in your project view.)